# Is it natural to say 'what's taking so long' here?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Alan is cooking when someone knocks on the door. He then asks his girlfriend Betty to take care of the cooking and goes answer the door himself. After quite a while, he doesn't come back to kitchen. Betty, actually a specter, can't cook, and worries about overcooking the dish. Then she says,

> What is taking so long, Alan?

Is the use of 'what is taking so long' natural here?

Comment: "Betty, actually a specter" - Betty is a ghost?

Comment: Yes, that explains why she sucks at cooking.

Comment: @Michael Lol but Betty is simultaneously good at cooking because vacuous truth?

Comment: @Michael  OK.  I ask because *specter* is a rather uncommon word to mean "ghost" in modern English.

Comment: @stangdon Thanks for the info! The story is meant to be about some ancient fairy tale.

Comment: @BCLC wut?? Is that supposed to be a joke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. This is because Alan 'doesn't come back to kitchen' 'after quite a while' and then Betty wonders about it.